# RegisterClientScriptBlock In userControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my jquery and javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //setup new person dialog
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        modal: true,
        //            show: "clip",
        //          hide: "explode",
        autoOpen: false,

        title: "انتخاب فاکتور",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });

    //setup edit person dialog
    $('#editPerson').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Edit Person",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
});

function showDialog(id) {
    $('#' + id).dialog("open");
}

function closeDialog(id) {
    $('#' + id).dialog("close");
}
```

The Code Is in UserControl .
i can show Dialog client Side :

and i can register code from server with this code :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(String), "script", "$(function() {showDialog('dialog');});", True)
```

this code works in page but not in user control.
how can i fix it?

HTML Code :

'> 
                        
                        
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            ' runat="server" />

Comment: Are you using the same `dialog` ID each time?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same @Nick ... @shaahin, do you have more than one time the same user control referenced on the same page?, cause you have a ClientIds trouble in there.

Comment: I'm not following, your code explicitly references `$('#dialog')` when creating the dialog, and you're explicitly passing that ID in with  `showDialog('dialog');`...how is it not being repeated?

Comment: sorry. it is because my low information  in jquery and web-Development.So How Can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this is the issue or not. Since UserCOntrol is a naming container your element id might have changed. So you need to get the id using [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx).

Change your code to something like this

```
$("#<%=yourbuttonid.ClientID%>").dialog("open");
```

Comment: i have html Control... ClientID?

Comment: Do you have `runat="server"` attribute set on that control?

Answer (score 1):

Check the rendered HTML code of your page. Is the order of your script blocks correct? The setup block should be first there, and the `showDialog` call block should be rendered somewhere below it. Is it your case?